# WebGrid filter checkbox values lost on page change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, pagination, filtering, webgrid

I'm using WebGrid and View Model in my MVC application. My Viewmodel has a int[ ] member called '**companiesfilter**' to take user's multiple selection from a company checkbox list to search a product database.

The ViewModel will be sent to controller by Ajax.BeginForm, and controller will return the SAME viewmodel with a product list to populate a partial view which is mainly a Webgrid and paged (server side paging).

It works well when I check some boxes, click the submit button, and get the result correctly. The problem is, when I click next page in WebGrid, it lost my multiselected values in **companiesfilter** on Controller side.

By debuging, I found that the View did send back **companiesfilter** with the data correctly, but MVC failed to bind the data when populate the viewmodel for controller. Could anyone tell me why?

The most interesting thing is, if I change companiesfilter to be string[ ], it works. HOWEVER, when Webgrid do paging, MVC feed the companiesfilter[0] with "1, 4, 5", not I supposed companiesfilter[0] = "1", companiesfilter[1] = "4", companiesfilter[2] = "5". Why it behaves like this?

Any suggestions to solve this issue? I prefer to use int[ ], not string[ ]. Thanks!

Here is my code for reference.

```
public class ProductSearchViewModel
{
    public List<Company> CompanyFullList { get; set; }
    public int[] CompaniesFilter { get; set; }
    //Search Result
    public IEnumerable<ProductInfor> ProductList { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult M_ProductSearchIndex(ProductSearchViewModel searchViewModel)
{
    search database...

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_M_ProductSearchResult", searchViewModel);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(searchViewModel);
    }        
}
```

My view:

```
@model MyApp.Models.ViewModels.ProductSearchViewModel
<div id="CompaniesChkboxs">
@foreach (var company in Model.CompanyFullList)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="CompaniesFilter" value="@company.Id", @(Html.Raw(company.Selected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> @company.CompanyName
}
</div>

@Html.Partial("_U_ProductSearchResult", Model)
```